# Let: $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What is the dimension of the range of $T$ if $T$ is $1-1$? Why?

What is the dimension of the null space of $T$ if $T$ is onto? Why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Use rank nullity theorem.

A linear transformation is one to one iff the Kernal of the map is trivial. Use this fact to solve the first part.

Also, use the definition of onto map and rank nullity theorem to solve the second prob.

I hope this help. Good luck!